# Angular fire auth : delete and logout a specif user with his uid

Tags: firebase, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I want to delete a user from the database so i need too logout and delete him from the auth. I use Angular fire auth but i don't know how too do this :

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.delete().then(() => {
          this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
        })
```

with a specif uid

Comment: Really want this

Answer (score 1):

This will work for deletion of currentUser.

```js
this.afAuth.currentUser.then(user => user?.delete())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a user via the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user):

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully deleted user");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
  });
```

The next time the user tries to get an ID token or reload, he/she will be signed out.